# Can the XmlElement annotation have multiple types?

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb

I have a list that is of a super type, i.e.

```
List<IFoo> foo
```

The list contains objects from two different subtypes:

```
public class FooBar implements IFoo{
}

public class FooType implements IFoo{
}
```

Is there are way to add multple types to the XmlElement annotation, i.e.

```
XmlElement(type={FooBar.class, FooType.class)
List<IFoo> foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple types for a list by using the annotation `XmlElements`.

E.g.

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(type=FooBar.class),
    @XmlElement(type=FooType.class)
})
List<IFoo> foo;
```

Answer (score -1):

A collection property can contain multiple types.  With this use case if you want to be able to round trip the document you will need some sort of type indicator.

**Option 1 - `@XmlElements`**

The `@XmlElements` annotation takes an array of `@XmlElement` annotation.  The purpose of this is to assign a unique element to identify each type.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html

**Option 2 - `@XmlElement(type=Object.class)`**

If you tell JAXB that the type is `Object` it will force each value to be written out with an `xsi:type` attribute to uniquely identify the type.  Since the value types will not be auto discovered you will need to pass then on to create the `JAXBContext` or reference the with a `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation.

Comment: Thanks Blaise, I used the XmlElements annotation in the end. I know you are well versed in this area so I hope you don't mind if I ask you another question. I need to serialise my java model to HTML, what is the best approach?

Comment: @user86834 - Something like?:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/using-jaxb-with-xslt-to-produce-html.html

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to get that working with Spring MVC's content negotiation mechanisms?